# Url.Action take route values from string variable

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 string variables in my cshtml:

```
string strController = "Controller";
string strAction = "Action";
string strQuerystring = "Pacode=2";
```

I am trying to generate an action on anchor tag :

```
<a href="@Url.Action(@strAction , @strController,@strQuerystring )" title="test">
  <span>@Test</span>
</a>
```

**Expected Output :** `Controller\Action?Pacode=2`

**Actual Output :** `Controller\Action?Length=8`

How do I pass the third parameter which is of string datatype while the action method expects as object route values ?

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `Url.Action` is `object routeValues` and `string` is `object` which has only one property (`Length`) you get `Length=8` because `"Pacode=2"` has 8 characters

Comment: Why not just declare it as `object strQuerystring = new { Pacode = 2"  };` ?

Comment: @stephen the value comes from a database. So i have it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very bad hack for now. Created an extension method.

It would be great if someone posts a better solution.

```
     public static string CustomUrlAction(this UrlHelper url, string controller = null, string action = null, string Query = null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller)&& string.IsNullOrEmpty(action) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query ))
                {
                    return "#";
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query) )
                {
                    return url.Action(action, controller);
                }
                return url.Action(action, controller) +"?"+ Query;
            }
```

& calling it as

```
<a href="@Url.CustomUrlAction(@strAction , @strController,@strQuerystring )" title="test">
  <span>@Test</span>
</a>
```